# Custom API Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Здравствуйте, как я могу в Rails сделать субдомен подобного вида: https://api.lochalhost:3000
и использовать его только в качестве api, не пропуская никакие роуты, кроме заданных именно под api.
Файл config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  constraints subdomain: 'api' do
     get '/order/:key', to: 'order#show'
  end

  root 'home#home'

  resources :profile
  resources :news
  resources :wikis

  resources :phone_numbers, only: [:new, :create]
  post 'phone_numbers/verify' => "phone_numbers#verify"

  devise_for :profiles, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' 
  }

  resources :users, only: [:index]
end
```

Файл /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   lochalhost
127.0.0.2   api.lochalhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Вы хотите в принципе сделать такой subdomain на локальной машине (запустить там приложение) или хотите, чтобы на localhost:3000 и на api.localhost:3000 были разные роуты?

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы localhost:3000 был самим приложением (сайтом), а api.localhost:3000 имел только get и post запросы для работы с API данного сайта.
К примеру routs: 
localhost:3000/registration,
localhost:3000/login,
localhost:3000/profile.
Но: 
api.localhost:3000/get_user_info/:id/key,
api.localhost:3000/get_any_values/key.

Comment: Приложение монолит? API и основное приложение - это один и тот же проект или разные?

Comment: Да, это один и тот же проект

Comment: Крч, автора интересует иметь одно приложение на одном хосте, которое отвечает на несколько доменных имён и с помощью роутинга передаёт их на обработку в разные места.

Comment: Тогда все равно возникает вопрос, если делать два приложения. Как в отдельном приложении построить маршрут типа api.localhost:3000/{key}

Comment: А, всё-таки разных? Вы редактируйте вопрос, не стесняйтесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле /etc/hosts (или С:\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts в Windows) заведите два домена

```
127.0.0.1 lochalhost
127.0.0.2 api.lochalhost
```

Обратите внимание, что IP-адреса разные, если они будут одинаковые — придется для фронт-части и api использовать разные порты.

Организовать разделение роутов по этим двум частям можно, воспользовавшись ограничениями на уровне constraints в файле config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  constraints subdomain: 'api' do
    # Роуты для API
    resource :clients
  end
  # Роуты для фронт-части
  root to: 'home#index'
end
```

Приложение придется запустить на 0.0.0.0, чтобы перехватить обращения к 127.0.0.1 и 127.0.0.2. Или, если используются разные порты — запустить две копии одного и того же приложения на разных портах.